# How do I compile this project? (Gleed2D)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, xna

I've downloaded the .zip of this project here:

https://github.com/SteveDunn/Gleed2D

And I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Trial and installed XNA 4.0. But when I try to open the included Gleed2D_Tool.sln file I get the error message:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Ui\Gleed2D.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Ui\Gleed2D.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Core\Gleed2D.Core.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Core\Gleed2D.Core.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Plugins\Gleed2D.Plugins.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Plugins\Gleed2D.Plugins.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Plugins.Krypton\Gleed2D.Plugins.Krypton.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.Plugins.Krypton\Gleed2D.Plugins.Krypton.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.InGame\Gleed2D.InGame.Windows.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.InGame\Gleed2D.InGame.Windows.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.InGame.Krypton\Gleed2D.InGame.Krypton.Windows.csproj : error  : The project file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\SteveDunn-Gleed2D-0ffaae5\src\Gleed2D.InGame.Krypton\Gleed2D.InGame.Krypton.Windows.csproj' cannot be opened.

The project type is not supported by this installation.
```

I'm stumped by the incredibly useless error message. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to compile?

Comment: Those projects may be looking for dependencies/plugins in vs to load correctly (like a MVC 3.0 would). Check their site for what dependencies you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project types in the project files you listed are C# and XNA

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Likely, as Mataniko suggested, you have either missed the C# installation as part of visual studio or XNA isn't properly installed.

There is a list of project type GUIDs at http://onlinecoder.blogspot.ca/2009/09/visual-studio-projects-project-type.html. Of course the list may not be complete because anybody can extend visual studio with a new project type with a fresh GUID.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have the full XNA 4.0 I only had the redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Visual Studio did you install C# with it? Can you create an XNA project? I have the same setup and it opened just fine so try doing that first.